# Parser Error Could not load type 'testconnect.index'

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, web

I have encountered an error that prevents me from uploading the webpage to the server. I managed to let it work without any errors when I am running visual studio.

Here's the error
[image]

However, when I removed **Inherits="testconnect.index"** , it can work but it cannot connect **index.aspx.cs** to **index.aspx**.

Like for example:

[image: index.aspx.cs class]

With lbl_test.Text inside the index.aspx
[image]

Does anyone knows how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to inherit from `testconnect.index`, but your class is named `index1`.  Can you change the class name to `index`?  Or, conversely, set the `Inherits` directive to inherit from `testconnect.index1`?

You have to specify the exact name of the class in order to reference it.  "Close enough" isn't close enough.

(Note also that Visual Studio is trying to tell you in your `index1` class that `lbl_test` doesn't exist.  Supposedly perhaps the designer partial class is `index`?  If that's the case, you'll probably want to just rename this partial class to `index` as well.)

Comment: Hello I tried changing the name, unfortunately it can't work at all.

Comment: It works now after I have changed the name from CodeBehind to CodeFile. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have got it working by changing **CodeBehind="index.master.cs**" to **CodeFile="index.master.cs"**. I learned that you will have to compile the file first if you want to use CodeBehind. Other than that, it is recommended not to name the aspx page exactly similar to masterpage.